# AJAX unable to call a springs controller

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am unable to give a call to my springs controller through AJAX.The console also shows no error or warnings.Here is my AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/updateUserStatus.html",
    data: "check ",
    success: function() { alert("success"); }
  });
});
```

And my relevant controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateUserStatus",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateUserStatus(@ModelAttribute("username") String username,
            BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println("inside update user status");
        userService.updateStatus(username); 
        return new ModelAndView("");
    }
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: If the print works, inspect your log, check if the controller forward to "". I guess it's because you return a ModelAndView. You need to write something to the response if I'm not mistaken and make the method returning void.

Comment: The print in also not working.Its going inside the ready function but its not calling ajax i suppose.

Comment: I made the method as get and still it didnt work.But if going through the url in address bar it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `URI` used was just `/updateUserStatus.html` instead it should have the full project name in its prefix because the call goes to `localhost:8080/updateUserStatus.html` in the former case.

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be given as `<%=request.getContextPath()%>/updateUserStatus` instead of   url: `/updateUserStatus.html`